# Mostrar el valor mas utilizado de un campo

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un codigo que me muestre el valor que mas se utiliza de un campo

En mi tabla **pedido** esta el campo **relleno** que contiene los siguientes valores (Frutilla, Leche, Condensada) entonces necesito que cada que se haga un pedido me muestre cual es el valor de relleno que mas se utiliza entre todos los **pedidos**.
O sea que me muestre cual es el relleno que mas se utiliza en mi tabla pedido

Tengo esta consulta que hace exactamente lo que quiero! pero como puedo guardar el resultado de esta consulta en una variable ?

```
SELECT relleno, COUNT( relleno ) as total
FROM pedido
GROUP BY relleno
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Cuando hablas de guardar tu resultado en una variable, a que lenguaje te refieres que lo obtenga?? me refiero a que si es en java, php, etc...

Comment: El lenguaje que utilizo es php y javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar así:

```
SELECT relleno
FROM pedido
GROUP BY relleno
ORDER BY COUNT( relleno ) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Desde PHP podrías hacer:

```
$relleno_habitual = $conn->query("
    SELECT relleno
    FROM pedido
    GROUP BY relleno
    ORDER BY COUNT( relleno ) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
")->fetch_row()[0];
```

Comment: @LuzMartinez con eso solo creaste una tabla con un campo que cuando entren mas registros no se va a volver a actualizar.. entendes eso no?